# Solve congruence with gcd

Tags: rsa

In a [solution](https://cr0w-ctf.gitlab.io/posts/securityfest19-infant-rsa/) to the problem of finding $q$ in

$$
c_1^{e_2}\cdot 5^{e_1e_2} - c_2^{e_1}\cdot 2^{e_1e_2} = q^{e_1e_2} \bmod n
$$

it is given as:

$$
q = \gcd\big(c_1^{e_2}\cdot 5^{e_1e_2} - c_2^{e_1}\cdot 2^{e_1e_2}, n\big)
$$

How can $q$ be found like that?

Comment: Without any clue about how $c_1$ and $c_2$ have been computed, it's hard to tell. Dumping homework here is not a good idea anyway.

Comment: @fgrieu updated with a link to the post, $c_1$ and $c_2$ are there. The post is very short

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way $c_1$ and $c_2$ have been obtained, algebra has shown that the quantity $z={c_1}^{e_2}\,5^{e_1\,e_2}-{c_2}^{e_1}\,2^{e_1\,e_2}$ is such that $z\equiv q^{e_1\,e_2}\pmod n$, where $n$ is an RSA modulus with $q$ one of the prime factors of $n$, $e_1$ and $e_2$ are RSA exponents valid for the modulus $n$.

From $n=p\,q$, we know that $q$ divides $n$.

From $z\equiv q^{e_1\,e_2}\pmod n$, and since $q$ divides $n$, we know that $z\equiv q^{e_1\,e_2}\pmod q$. Since neither $e_1$ nor $e_2$ are zero, it holds $q^{e_1\,e_2}\equiv0\pmod q$. Therefore, $z\equiv0\pmod q$, that is $q$ divides $z$.

Hence, $q$ is a common divisor of $n$ and $z$. With $n=p\,q$ with $p$ prime, it follows that one of the following holds:

- $z=0$
- $\gcd(z,n)$ is $q$
- $\gcd(z,n)$ is $n$.

The way $z$ was constructed gives no particular reason to believe that $p$ divides $z$, and that's highly unlikely for a random integer. It follows that $\gcd(z,n)=q$ is the only likely possibility in the above three.

The quantity ${c_1}^{e_2}\,5^{e_1\,e_2}-{c_2}^{e_1}\,2^{e_1\,e_2}\bmod n$ can efficiently be computed from givens, and that allows to compute $\gcd(z,n)$ (since the first step of that can be to reduce $z$ modulo $n$), and thus allows to compute $q$.

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing some math here. Could you explain why "it follows that one of the following holds"?

Comment: @tasera: We proved that $q$ divides $z$. It is known that $n=p\,q$ with $p$ and $q$ primes. $z=0$ is a possibility matching the above. Otherwise, for $z\ne0$, we can define and compute $g=\gcd(z,n)$. Since $g$ divides $n$ by definition of $\gcd$, it is one of $1$, $p$, $q$, or $n$. Since $q$ divides $n$ and $z$, and $1<q$, we can't have $g=1$. If we had $g=p$, and $p\ne q$, both $p$ and $q$ would divides $z$, hence $n$ would divides $z$, hence $g\ge n$, thus $g\ne p$. That leaves $q$ and $n$ as the only possibilities for $g$. Thus one of $z=0$, $g=q$, $g=n$ holds, as stated in the answer.